# Search and replace image dimension within content in mysql?

Tags: mysql, image, wordpress, replace

I have a wordpress blog with over 500 posts. The first post image is always 550px wide and the hight is between the 300px and 450px.

The blog design has been updated and the first post image is now 600px width and between the 350px and 500px high. I have manually downloaded the first images, and resized them from 550 to 600, with some minor quality lose.

The easiest thing would be to search and replace in the database. Look for width="550" and replace it with width="600", but then there is the problem with the height. This is not a fixed variable, like 550.

If wordpress images had their own table, I could simply do something like

```
update  wp_posts
set height = height*1.09;
```

But in the case of wordpress, this cannot be done because the information is stored in post_content and looks like this:

```
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4352" title="Image Title" src="http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/image.jpg" alt="image" width="550" height="351" />
```

How can the height be changed in proportion to the width, in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really tough question. But it's a fun question too.

Anyway, here it goes. To extract the width and height from the post_content images, create a view

```
create view temp_images (id, width, height) as
select id,
       ExtractValue(post_content, '/img/@width'),
       ExtractValue(post_content, '/img/@height')
from wp_posts
where post_content like '<img%'
      and ExtractValue(post_content, '/img/@width') = 550;
```

You don't need the width in your case, but if you want to play with, it's here.
Now, you have the image post's id and corresponding width and height. With this, you can update the image elements width and height in two steps

```
update wp_posts, temp_images
set post_content = UpdateXml(post_content, '/img/@width', 'width="600"')
where wp_posts.id = temp_images.id;

update wp_posts, temp_images
set post_content = UpdateXml(post_content, '/img/@height',
                             concat('height="', round(height * 1.09), '"'))
where wp_posts.id = temp_images.id;
```

and finally clean up, of course

```
drop view temp_images;
```

and last but not least, here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2edf/1/0) for testing and playing.

Comment: Thank you. Great idea to temporally “park” the data. To be clear, it seems that this code will change the height of all images by * 1.09, rather than only the images that where 550 wide? For example there could be images in the gallery that are 800x600, or images within the post that are smaller than 550px.

Comment: @Lisa Ok, I missed that then. So, you want to change only images, which are exactly 550px wide? Or have some other attribute?

Comment: @Lisa I updated the answer, if it's just the images 550px wide.

Comment: Thank you for the update. This seems to give an syntax error SQL-query: 

UPDATE wp_posts,
temp_images SET post_content = UpdateXml( post_content, '/img/@width', 'width="600"' ) ) WHERE wp_posts.id = temp_images.id;


MySQL retourneerde:  
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
 where wp_posts.id = temp_images.id' at line 2

Comment: I tried it in 3 steps and it worked. Thank you. One more question. It there a way to round the number. 381 pixels has turned in to 416.328987

Comment: @Lisa Yes, that was one brace too much, fixed. Take the obvious [`round()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) ;-) Please see updated answer and SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was reading about round() and experimenting in SQL Fiddle. BTW Thank you for introducing me to SQL Fiddle, give me a chance to play and learn SQL.